# Can't exclude devices from Google Play when integrity is not MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY

Tags: android, google-play-integrity-api

Looking at https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/additional-tools

At the end of the page, it explains how to exclude devices from seeing your app in the store if the device does not meet MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY and/or MEETS_BASIC_INTEGRITY.

My question is is how can I do it with MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY?

Is there a list of devices somewhere that has strong integrity?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.